# Sorting and ordering two expense lists by a third list of categories using Excel 2016

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel-2016, sorting, vlookup

I want to use Excel 2016 to sort two expense lists by a third list of categories.

The first catch is that I want to place the value in the same cell like the categoris list – It's not a simple sort, It's something like sort + vlookup combines.

The  second catch is that the order of the categories in the category list isn't necessarily in the same order as in the other lists.

Here is a illustration of what I want to do:
[image: what I want to do]

I've tried using vlookup but I haven't succeeded. Do You have an Idea  how I can do it ?
Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions. On N2, enter the formula:

```
=IFNA(INDEX($F$2:$F$9,MATCH($M2,$E$2:$E$9,0)),"")
```

On O2, enter the formula:

```
=IFNA(INDEX($I$2:$I$10,MATCH($M2,$H$2:$H$10,0)),"")
```

Drag both cells down to fill the other cells.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ReddyLutonadio. As I understand it - the IFNA isn't essential for the formula, It's "only" for insuring the formula against N/A values.Am I right ?

Comment: @jonatr Yes. For example, Transportation is one of the categories t check, but there is no data for it. Without IFNA, the result will be #N/A. With it,we display an empty string "" instead of N/A